# Primefaces datatable livescroll and lazy not working in version 5.2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i updated Primefaces version 5.1 to 5.2

After that all my DataTables with following structure are no longer working.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{device.lazyDataModelHosts}" var="host"
         style="font-size: larger;" 
         rowIndexVar="rowNr"
             rendered="#{not empty device.managedServiceList}"
             scrollRows="50"
             lazy="true"
             liveScroll="true"
             scrollable="true"
             scrollHeight="150"
             selectionMode="single"
             emptyMessage="#{device.emptyMessage}"
             id="tbl"
             resizableColumns="true"
             styleClass="auto-resize"
            >
...
</p:dataTable>
```

Any suggestions?
Thx, flo

Comment: There should be no problem like the blog says in part of Migration: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3491. Try removing the attributes one to one and check the behavior. Check the JS console in the browser and if there is an error then edit your question with it.

Comment: and 'not working' is not something we can help with... Waaaaayyyy to vague. [mcve]. And read the migration guide